# Is it possible to get derived type from base class without template?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have referred to many documents here,
but I have a question because I cannot get a clear answer.

To help you understand, you have explicitly renamed functions, variables, and classes.

```
// interface.h
class Base {
    ...
};

class Derived_A : public Base {
    ...
    void foo_A() { return 1; }
};

class Derived_B : public Base {
    ...
    void foo_B() { return 2; }
};

// manager.h && manager.cpp
class Manager
{
    static std::vector<Base*> g_lists;
    // It also proceed below.
    // g_lists.push_back(new Derived_A);
    // g_lists.push_back(new Derived_B);

public:
    // How can I changed this method ?
    static auto getDerived(char _type);
}
...

auto Manager::getDerived(char _type)
{
    auto base = g_lists[get_index_from_type(_type)];

    if (base == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    if (_type == 'A')
        return (dynamic_cast<Derived_A>(base))
    else if (_type == 'B')
        return (dynamic_cast<Derived_B>(base))
    else
        return nullptr;
}

// main.cpp

int main()
{
    // I want to using like this
    auto ptr = Manager::getDerived('B')
    ptr->foo_B();
}
```

I already know that it is possible if use the template as below.

```
template<class Type>
Type* getDerived(char _type)
{
    if (g_lists[idx])
        return dynamic_cast<Type*>(g_lists[idx]);
    else return nullptr;
}

// user side
auto ptr = getDerived<Derived_A>('A');
```

However, I want to make a code that avoids using class "Derived_" from the user's point of view.

Is there any good way for me?

Comment: What type would `ptr` be?

Comment: What if we did `char type; cin >> type; auto ptr = Manager::getDerived(ptr);`? Then what type would `ptr` be?

Comment: @user253751 If the type is not 'A' or 'B', I want to treat it as nullptr. Therefore, I used auto, but I found this impossible through the answer.

Comment: auto just means you're too lazy to write the type. There still has to be a type so what should the type be?

Comment: Derived classes are based on 'Base', so first, I tried return with Base*, but in this case, I can't access Derived's method. So I hope to variable return type. I don't think about it from a compilation point of view.

Comment: There's no such thing as a variable return type. The return type has to be a type. No ifs or buts.

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, it's not possible what you are asking, because a function/method can have a single `return` type, which is decided at compile time.
The most basic way is to return the `Base` pointer/reference:

```
static Base* getDerived(char _type);
```

And whichever method you intend to invoke, should be `virtual`:

```
class Base {
  virtual void foo_A ();
  virtual void foo_B ();
};
```

This way a correct method `ptr->foo_B()` will be invoked. It will also save you from lot of boilerplate code. Remember that the cost of `virtual` method is insignificant for the benefits it provide and are meant for such scenario.

Reference from [Bjarne Stroustrup's official page](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation):

> In my experience, the efficiency reason is usually misplaced fear. In C++, virtual function calls are so fast that their real-world use for a class designed with virtual functions does not to produce measurable run-time overheads compared to alternative solutions using ordinary function calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. In fact, I have many classes derived from Base, not both A and B classes. Then is the best option for me to use the template listed in the question?

Comment: @mystes If you need such a function it may be a hint of a general design bug. If the outside code must know what the object really is, you violate against OOP rules. You should ask your self: Why I need the object internal details? The object itself should now how to process some requests not the outside code should do it. If the outside code must know the object itself, it must always be modified if the implementation of the derived class changes. Exactly the opposite what we want... Give a clear design a chance!

Comment: @mystes, use template if you are OK to go with CRTP based solution. But in such a case, you have to mention the derived type explicitly, which you may not want as per the question. However as "Klaus" mentioned in above comment, it looks like a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The returning type `auto` in your `auto Manager::getDerived(...)` is actually resolving the return type in compile-time to `SOME_TYPE` when you do `return (dynamic_cast<SOME_TYPE>(base))`. So you need a template for your compiler to know what `SOME_TYPE` is.

Answer (score 0):

if the type is known at compile-time, you can change it to template parameter

```
template<char type>
auto getDerived()
{
    Base* base = GetAsBase(type);

    if constexpr (type == 'A')
        return static_cast<Derived_A*>(base); // static_cast, it should success afaict
    else if constexpr (type == 'B')
        return static_cast<Derived_B*>(base); 
    else
        return nullptr;
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto ptr = getDerived<'B'>()
    ptr->foo_B();
}
```